# External Access to Server

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, centos-7, ssh-tunnel

I've set up a basic CentOS 7 server as an attempt to learn server architecture and maintenance, as well as for personal use. I am currently attempting to set up secure access to the server via ssh tunneling using my laptop which I can then expand on with setting up nfs over ssh and so on. Could someone explain the process of setting up a ssh tunnel from a CentOS 7 server to my windows 10 laptop? I can't quite understand it

Comment: What part you cannot understand?

Comment: @harrymc the process of setting up my server to be port forwarded so I can then connect to it from outside my LAN on say my laptop

Answer (score 0):

[Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
is done in the router, forwarding traffic from external IP:port to internal IP:port.

Information about creating a port forwarding is best found in the manual
of your router, available from the manufacturer or found on the Internet.

If you didn't find the information in these sources ,
there exists also a website dedicated to Port Forwarding: https://portforward.com/

This website contains general information about the subject, as well as detailed
instructions for many router models. If your model is not there, search for one
that is near enough.